# Shared dict of multiprocessing.Lock in python3

Tags: python-multiprocessing

Is it possible to have a shared dict of Locks in python3? I need multiple locks because I want to protect a dict of shared resources. Each resource gets a lock:

```py
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()

locks = manager.dict({key : manager.Lock() for key in range(100)})
shared_resource = manager.dict({key : SomeClass() for key in range(100)})

# later in a multi-processed function
def foo(key):
  # ...
  locks[key].acquire()
  shared_resource[key] = ...
  locks[key].release()
  # ...
```

This toy example would fail with:

```
multiprocessing.managers.RemoteError: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unserializable message: ('#RETURN', <unlocked _thread.lock object at 0x7f9a4c9dc468>)
```

Any idea how to get around this problem? I could use conditional variables? Or how would you protect a list of resources?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, seems like it's a bug with `ptyhon3.5`.

With `python3.6` it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's possible. I don't get an error when I run this code...I just substituted SomeClass with 'x'. So maybe there's an issue there.
Also, using a context manager to acquire and release the lock is a nice little abstraction...

```
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
locks = {key : manager.Lock() for key in range(100)}
shared_resource = {key : 'x' for key in range(100)}

# later in a multi-processed function
def foo(key):
   # ...
  with locks[key]:
  shared_resource[key] = 'xoyo'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=foo, args=(1,))
    p.start()
    p = Process(target=foo, args=(1,))
    p.start()
    p = Process(target=foo, args=(1,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i forgot one important detail: `manager.dict({...})```. Those are not normal `dicts` but shared ones through `Manager`